# how to control fan on ubuntu in lenovo legion y530

Tags: lenovo, overheating, fan

On a Lenovo Legion Y530 running Ubuntu 18.04, ideally I don't hear the fan running. When I do <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>, the fan start to run very fast; the laptop start to heat and after some time it run for certain period of time.

I tried [lm-sensors](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto) and [pwmconfig](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/pwmconfig.8.html) which responds with:

```
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

If pwmconfig is not going to work, can you tell me an alternative so that I can run my laptop fan continuously in certain seed.

Comment: did you look in the device BIOS for any fan settings? You can often find fan settings in BIOS or UEFI, although I don't know that for your Laptop.
Just try to access your BIOS on Startup.
You can normally access it with `F1` or `F2` at startup.

Comment: after you recommend me that i went to BIOS and i search everywhere but i didn't find the fan control in in bios. I you have any idea than please tell me.

Comment: What is Fn+Alt+q for? Uninstall `pwmconfig`. Try `thermald`.

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/thermald.8.html and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues may be helpful.

Comment: pwmconfig requires that you run sensors-detect first and it usually needs to detect a SuperIO Controller.  thermald requires the presence of /sys/class/thermal.  thinkfan requires /proc/acpi/ibm/fan

Comment: I am the new in this linux environment and i am still in learning phase so if you could tell me the processes than that would really help me. i have the intel digital thermal sensor (driver 'coretemp') when i use lm-sensors.

Comment: Hi, could you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Found an AppImage to switch on "Extreme Cooling". Works as expected. Run it as root.

https://odintdh.itch.io/extremecooling4linux

Comment: It still works. Lenovo Legion Y540, Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: Works on Pop OS 21.04 as well, needs to be run as sudo in my case. I have a Lenovo Legion 5 17ACH6H, this is the only working solution for me.